# Handling Rest Services with varying response using spring rest template

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

I have a rest endpoint say invalidate a session which returns nothing when the session is invalidated successfully but returns a JSON response when the session is already invalid.

I did not find a good way to handle cases like these using Spring Rest Template, any help/recommendations appreciated.

Comment: What HTTP response codes are returned for the two scenarios that you mentioned. If 200 is returned for the success scenario and 4xx/5xx for the error scenario and all your error response JSONs have a uniform structure, then you can add a ResponseErrorHandler in your RestTemplate, in which you can deserialize the response body to the error class and throw that as an exception...

Comment: @Ranjith Thanks, will try and post the update here